# showing svg with img tag in angular with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I am trying to show images with svg as src with following code but svgs are not getting displayed.

```
<div ng-repeat="col in collections track by $index">
<img class="class1" ng-src="{{col.svgurl}}" alt="{{col.number}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.5? Apparently SVG support was made opt-in in the latest version due to security concerns: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/181fc567d873df065f1e84af7225deb70a8d2eb9

Comment: I am using angular 1.4.4